# I have a question on typeorm in the Generated() decorator

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I have two fields that need to be automatically generated.

they are:

```
columns: [
          {
            name: 'ID_TIPO_ENTREGA',
            type: 'uuid',
            isPrimary: true,
            generationStrategy: 'uuid',
            default: 'uuid_generate_v4()',
          },
          {
            name: 'CD_TIPO_ENTREGA',
            type: 'int',
            generationStrategy: 'increment',
            default: 2021,
          },
```

but CD_TIPO_ENTREGA field is not being generated automatically.

Is and my entity file :

```
@Entity(TABLE_NAME)
class TiposEntrega {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: ID_TIPO_ENTREGA })
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'int', name: CD_TIPO_ENTREGA, default: 2021 })
  @Generated('increment')
  cdTipoEntrega: number;
```

my ID_TIPO_ENTREGA field, generates the uuid perfectly,
remembering that I'm using the postgres database.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the following to my field:

```
{
            name: 'CD_TIPO_ENTREGA',
            type: 'integer',
            isGenerated: true,
            generationStrategy: 'increment',
          },
```

I managed to solve from this [link](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4067#issuecomment-955783594)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.